# Return undefined error when getting button value

Tags: javascript, iframe, target, cesiumjs

I have a  the following codes. I am facing the issue of receiving undefined in the alert. Do any one know why?

```
<div><button class='hello' value='hello1'>Show</button></div>

viewer.infoBox.frame.addEventListener('load', function() {
       
        // Now that the description is loaded, register a click listener inside
        // the document of the iframe.
       
        viewer.infoBox.frame.contentDocument.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
           
            // The document body will be rewritten when the selectedEntity changes,
            // but this body listener will survive.  Now it must determine if it was
            // one of the clickable buttons.
            
             alert(e.target.value);
         
        }, false);
    }, false);
```

Updated: I managed to get it to work on this [sandbox](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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), but unable to do so on localhost. Any idea?

Comment: What is viewer.infoBox.frame - please click edit and `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan I have updated with an example.

Comment: No idea. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The click event listener likely doesn't have e.target.value. Perhaps you were just looking for e.target. You can console.log(e) and see every value that it gives you.

Comment: It likely has something to do with viewer.infoBox.frame.contentDocument.body then. What is that? From my research it's a map. I've seen people use the event "tap" rather than "click". Could try that.